# Differentiation Product Rule Question on $x^2(x-1)^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing, factoring

I have a question:

> $x^2(x-1)^3$

Which I am supposed to solve using the product rule but it seems that I have hit a dead end with the algebraic part.
Here's my working so far:

$u = x^2$

$u' = 2x$

$v = (x-1)^3$

$v' = 3(x-1)^2$

$(uv)'= (x-1)^32x+x^23(x-1)^2$

This is the part I'm stuck on.

How can I move on?

Comment: Can you state precisely what you're looking for?

Comment: You have basically already written the correct answer (apart from a small mistake in the last line), now it's only a matter of making it prettier. Perhaps you can take $x(x-1)^2$ as a common term...

Comment: Just a side note: You have written "I have a question: $x^2(x-1)^3$ which I am supposed to solve (...)." Notice that you're not supposed to **solve** this because it's not an equation. Rather, I assume, you're supposed to find the derivative of the function
$$
f(x) = x^2 (x-1)^3
$$
Clear wording is very important in mathematics.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have to simplify the last line,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, $$2x(x-1)^3+3x^2(x-1)^2=x(x-1)^2(2(x-1)+3x)=x(x-1)^2(5x-2).$$